# How do i use fontawesome icons in TinyMce editor?

Tags: css, tinymce, admin-css

I'm trying to add a youtube button in TinyMce editor.

here is a recent-posts.js file which is in the js folder of the theme directory.

```
(function() {
   tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.buttons', {
      init : function(ed, url) {

         //for recent post button
         ed.addButton('recentposts', {
            title : 'Recent posts',
            image : url + '/youtube.png',
            onclick : function() {
               var posts = prompt("Number of posts", "");
               var text = prompt("List Heading", "");

               if (text != null && text != ''){
                  if (posts != null && posts != '')
                     ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '[recent-posts posts="'+posts+'"]'+text+'[/recent-posts]');
                  else
                     ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '[recent-posts]'+text+'[/recent-posts]');
               }
               else{
                  if (posts != null && posts != '')
                     ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '[recent-posts posts="'+posts+'"]');
                  else
                     ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '[recent-posts]');
               }
            }
         });


         //for youtube video
          ed.addButton('youtube', {
            title : 'YouTube',
            text: 'YouTube',          
            onclick : function() {
               var id = prompt("Video id", "");
               var text = prompt("Video Heading", "");

               if (text != null && text != ''){
                  if (id != null && id != '')
                     ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '[yt id="'+id+'"]'+text+'[/yt]');
               }
               else{
                  if (id != null && id != '')
                     ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '[yt posts="'+id+'"]');
               }
            }
         });

      },
      createControl : function(n, cm) {
         return null;
      },
      getInfo : function() {
         return {
            longname : "me The Most Brilliant",
            author : 'me',
            authorurl : 'http://www.google.com',
            infourl : 'http://www.google.com',
            version : "1.0"
         };
      }
   });
   tinymce.PluginManager.add('buttons', tinymce.plugins.buttons);
})();
```

code in functions.php is

```
function register_button( $buttons ) {
   array_push( $buttons,"recentposts", "youtube" );
   return $buttons;
}

function add_plugin( $plugin_array ) {
   $plugin_array['buttons'] = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/recent-posts.js';
   return $plugin_array;
}

function my_recent_posts_button() {

   if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') ) {
      return;
   }

   if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true' ) {
      add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'add_plugin' );
      add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'register_button' );
   }

}

add_action('init', 'my_recent_posts_button');
```

In place of `image : url+'/youtube.png'` i'm trying to use `text :'<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>'`

But in text editor insted of font awesome icon , it is just showing as a text as it is.
Where should i place the font awesome file and how should i call it and how to use it in TinyMce?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to add a FontAwesome icon by passing it directly to the `ed.addButton();` method unfortunately.

You can try a workaround however. If you leave the `image : url+'/youtube.png'` parameter out of the method then it will automatically create an empty `<span>` with the class of `mceIcon` & another class of `mce_[plugin_name]`.

You can then use CSS to style that `<span>` element however you would like.

You can use FontAwesome directly in your CSS now, something like this (make sure you change `.mce_[plugin_name]` place-hoder class used here to your actual class):

```
span.mce_[plugin_name] {
    position: relative;
}

span.mce_[plugin_name]:before {
    content: "\f166"; /* Value for the Youtube icon*/
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
/*--adjust as necessary--*/
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is how I load my FontAwesome CSS file. I have adapted to load for the admin area for what you need to do however. I call it from the BootStrap CDN, but you could download the CSS file and load it from your theme or plugin folder using the same `admin_enqueue_scripts();` function.

```
// Load Font Awesome
function royal_enqueue_awesome() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-font-awesome', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), '4.0.3' );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'royal_enqueue_awesome' );
```

Comment: I'm not using a plugin.

Comment: and fontawesome's youtube icon comes using `<i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>`. How do i use this in css?

Comment: What you are doing in your code above is adding your own TinyMCE plugin - I'm not referring to using a WordPress plugin :-) I suggest looking at this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/guide-to-creating-your-own-wordpress-editor-buttons--wp-30182) to get a good overview of the process as well, might be helpful :-)

Comment: The `<i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>` is the HTML markup that the FontAwesome CSS is applied to by default. You can apply it to other elements using CSS Pseudo Selectors as I have done in my code if you so wish as well.

Comment: I'm not getting any span element if i leave `image:`. I can access the button using its id which is #mce_17, and i can use admin_head action hook, and i can change its background color etc. I'm confused where should i put the fontawesome folder i downloaded and should i just call it's css file in functions.php? after that what should i do? let me put the entire code.

Comment: Yes you can use the ID as well. You need to use `wp_enqueue_style` function to add the FontAwesome CSS file to your website before being able to call the CSS I supplied to you previously.

Comment: i'm not sure where are you getting that "\f1666" value from , there is no documentation about it in fontawesome website

Comment: it is not working with the way yous said, the element is `<button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">YouTube</button>` , all i need to do is replace Youtube with <i fa fa-youtube></i>

Comment: The "\f1666" value us UTF-8 character code. You can reference these on the [FontAwesome Cheatsheet](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/)

Comment: `function tinymce_style(){

 ?>
 <style>
         #mce_17{

          content: "\f166"; /* Value for the Youtube icon*/
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-decoration: inherit;

         }
        
 </style>

 <?php
}

add_action('admin_head', 'tinymce_style');` i'm using this

Comment: What is the `<div>` element that wraps the `<button>` element?

Comment: `function thought_script(){

    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'thought_script');` and this to add fontawesome css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15473/discussion-between-matt-royal-and-user1906399).

Comment: `<div id="mce_17" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-last" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mce_17" role="button" aria-label="YouTube"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-youtube"></i></button></div>` this is what i get from google inspect element

Comment: i need 20 reputation to chat

Comment: Try this as you were using the wrong action and loading FontAwesome to the website not the Dashboard as you need to... `function thought_script(){ wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'); } add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'thought_script');`

Comment: now i get `<i class="mce-ico mce-i-youtube"></i>` inside button element , but it is not working.

Comment: Now i figured it out, it is not span element it is i element which will come if no text or image is specified. so i just needed to target i.mce-i-youtube class, which is different as you mentioned. I was looking for span element. ty for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the following on WordPress 4.6.1

I originally looked up this process to help create a button that would produce a shortcode. Based on some various posts, I originally used the following addButton parameters within my javascript file to decor my TINYMCE button...

```
ed.addButton('wpse72394_button', { title: 'title of my button', cmd: 'wpse72394_inser', image: url + '/path/to/image.png' });
```

...But I didn't want to create a new button from scratch or just a text label. I instead wanted to reference an existing icon in WordPress.  I discovered that I could easily swap out the **image:** parameter for an **icon:** parameter like so...

```
ed.addButton('wpse72394_button', { title: 'Insert shortcode', cmd: 'wpse72394_insert_shortcode', icon: 'wp_code' });
```

Within WordPress, if you look within

path-to-site\wp-includes\js\tinymce\plugins\wordpress\plugins.js

you will discover various options like...

```
      wp_help
      wp_more
      wp_page
      wp_code
```

I don't believe these are fontawesome icons, but they are close enough for me in getting the job done without adding additional css or cdn link references.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a greatly simple solution for this.

Firstly add the FontAwesome library to WordPress Backend by creating and adding it to **admin_init**

```
function fontawesome_dashboard() {
   wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css'); 
}

add_action('admin_head', 'fontawesome_dashboard', 11);
```

Then on you javascript file:

```
ed.addButton('recentposts', {
            title : 'Recent posts',
            icon: ' fa fa-camera-retro', // notice a space before the 'fa'
```

This kind of hack worked for me. I am sure it will work for you as well :)

Comment: This works great (running WP 5.7.2 and FontAwesome 5.15.1). Just make sure, to pay attention to the SPACE before the first class LOL